# ORA-24344: success with compilation error in Oracle Apex when compiling a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on my university database project in Oracle Apex and I'm getting the `ORA-24344: success with compilation error` when trying to compile the body package with the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY band_price_package AS 
-- Function that checks if a band has a manager 
FUNCTION agent_present(band_id BAND.Band_id%TYPE)
RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
BEGIN
 IF BAND.Agent_firstname IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_lastname IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_phone IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_email IS NULL
 THEN
  RETURN FALSE;
 ELSE
  RETURN TRUE;
 END IF;
END agent_present;
-- Procedure that gets the band hire price including agent fee 
PROCEDURE get_band_cost(band_id IN BAND.Band_id%TYPE, 
                        band_cost OUT BOOKING.Agreed_band_price%TYPE) 
IS 
BEGIN 
 IF agent_present(band_id) 
 THEN
  band_cost := BOOKING.Agreed_band_price * 1.25;
 ELSE
  band_cost := BOOKING.Agreed_band_price;
 END IF;
END get_band_cost;

END band_price_package; 
/
```

The following specification has compiled without any errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE band_price_package AS 
-- Function that checks if a band has a manager 
FUNCTION agent_present(band_id   BAND.Band_id%TYPE)
RETURN BOOLEAN;
-- Procedure that gets the band hire price including agent fee 
PROCEDURE get_band_cost(band_id IN BAND.Band_id%TYPE, 
                        band_cost OUT BOOKING.Agreed_band_price%TYPE); 

END band_price_package; 
/
```

Comment: The `agent_present` function refers to things like `band.agent_firstname` that aren't declared anywhere. You need to review the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access tables directly in PL/SQL; so

```
 IF BAND.Agent_firstname IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_lastname IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_phone IS NULL
    AND BAND.Agent_email IS NULL
```

is invalid syntax. You need to use an SQL statement inside the PL/SQL block like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95188/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE BAND(
  band_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Agent_firstname VARCHAR2(200),
  Agent_lastname  VARCHAR2(200),
  Agent_phone     VARCHAR2(20),
  Agent_email     VARCHAR2(100)
)
/

CREATE TABLE BOOKING(
  Agreed_band_price NUMBER(10,2)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE band_price_package AS 
  -- Function that checks if a band has a manager 
  FUNCTION agent_present(
    i_band_id   BAND.Band_id%TYPE
  )
  RETURN BOOLEAN;

  -- Procedure that gets the band hire price including agent fee 
  PROCEDURE get_band_cost(
    i_band_id   IN  BAND.Band_id%TYPE, 
    o_band_cost OUT BOOKING.Agreed_band_price%TYPE
  );
END band_price_package; 
/
```

Then you can do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY band_price_package AS 
  -- Function that checks if a band has a manager 
  FUNCTION agent_present(
    i_band_id BAND.Band_id%TYPE
  )
  RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    agent_exists NUMBER(1,0);
  BEGIN
    -- Check if an agent exists in the table.
    SELECT 1
    INTO   agent_exists
    FROM   band
    WHERE  band_id = i_band_id
    AND    (   Agent_firstname IS NOT NULL
           OR  Agent_lastname  IS NOT NULL
           OR  Agent_phone     IS NOT NULL
           OR  Agent_email     IS NOT NULL );

    RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
  END agent_present;

-- Procedure that gets the band hire price including agent fee 
  PROCEDURE get_band_cost(
    i_band_id   IN  BAND.Band_id%TYPE, 
    o_band_cost OUT BOOKING.Agreed_band_price%TYPE
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    -- Not completed; since it is your homework.
    NULL;
  END get_band_cost;
END band_price_package; 
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I didn't realise this would require an SQL statement in order to work.

Answer (score -1):

Which tool do you use to access database? In SQLPlus, you should run `SHOW ERR` which would tell you what's wrong with your code. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return boolean is
  2  begin
  3    return 1 = 2   --> missing semi-colon
  4  end;
  5  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for FUNCTION F_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
         following:
         * & - + ; / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and or ||
         multiset
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

SQL>
```

GUI tools usually have the "Errors" tab in Object Navigator which display the same.

As of your code, a few blind guesses (as we don't have your tables and can't test it ourselves):

- function AGENT_PRESENT accepts BAND_ID as a parameter, which is declared as a BAND.BAND_ID column datatype. You can't reference other BAND table columns the way you do - you should SELECT those columns into variables (or, if you want, declare a rowtype variable and work with it) and then detect whether they are present or not.
- procedure GET_BAND_COST calls BOOKING.AGREED_BAND_PRICE which is unknown (at least, it is not declared in that package). So, what is it? Is it a table column? If so, you can't modify it that way - use UPDATE instead.